# Point Spread Function

Tags: signal-processing, image-processing

I am given the function $I_m(x,y)$ of a rendered image as well as the function $I(x,y)$ of the real image. Now I need to find the point spread function PSF. I know that

$I_m(x,y) = \iint I(x,y)PSF(x-\mu, y-\nu)d\mu d\nu$.

Does someone have a hint how to start?

Answer (score 0):

In the Fourier domain, the convolution

$$g(x,y) = \iint f(x,y) \; h(x-\mu, y-\nu) \; d\mu d\nu$$

can be written as a multiplication

$$G = F \; H \; ,$$

with the upper-case letters indicating the functions in the Fourier domain. Here, $h$ is your PSF.

To obtain the PSF from $f$ and $g$, you can now do

$$H = \frac{G}{F} \; .$$

Of course, in practice this has numerical instability: where $F$ has small values, the computed $H$ will be non-sensical. Also, where $F$ is zero, so is $G$ (by construction), and the value of $H$ cannot be known. Wiener filtering introduces regularization to make this inverse filtering (called deconvolution) stable. See [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48821963/7328782) for a practical implementation of this process.